# Não tenho a opção excluir do projeto para um folder e seus arquivos

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Antes tínhamos um NuGet próprio para instalar nossas DLL's e etc. Bem, agora não mais usamos o NuGet. Acontece que baixei do repositório um projeto para corrigir um bug, ele pede o NuGet.exe. Como eu não necessito dele, fui remover do projeto e ao clicar com o direito, para esse folder ou seus arquivos dentro, não tenho essa opção, apenas delete. Mas delete vai dar pau, vai continuar a pedir o arquivo. Como eu removo do projeto nessa situação? No aguardo.